# How to display different column values into a listbox or textbox in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to display three different columns of a table into a listbox or textbox. I am not sure which one to use. How I can do that? I have attached the image for Reference.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXLwG.png)

Comment: Use a table with 3 rows and 2 columns

Answer (score 0):

get all the values from the database  into some collection List and then bind the values to listbox or textbox